# Is there a downside to going multiple days without sleeping?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

While adventuring and completing side quests, I'd realized I'd gone days without stopping to rest and cashing in my experience (thanks to those nighttime hunts). My party has started complaining of being tired and looking forward to a good night's rest. **Are their conversations just flavor or are there any negative effects to keeping my party up for multiple days without sleeping?**

Comment: Hot Network Questions, here we come...

Comment: As a reminder, comments are for the actual question itself -- not unnecessary chatter.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Apparently there **is** a penalty for going more than 3 days without sleep, according to the [wikia page on Lodgings](http://finalfantasyxv.wiki.fextralife.com/Lodgings):

> The party can go 3 days without sleep, after which they lose any status buffs.

According to an [an interview](http://kotaku.com/final-fantasy-xvs-director-breaks-down-the-newest-trail-1673513161) with Final Fantasy XV's director:

> The way it works is, if you don't sleep for long periods, you don't get a negative status – rather it's the opposite. "Buffs" are statuses with positive effects, and you stop getting those. Basically, things like increased spirits or feeling good or other added bonuses stop getting applied if you don't sleep for long periods of time.

---

However, you *can* maximize your EXP gains by refraining from sleeping. If you rack up a ton of EXP and spend 30k to sleep in the nice hotel that gives you 3x EXP boost (it's in Altissia, talk to the receptionist on the **right**), you will be able to level up a lot more than if you sleep every night, as you probably can't afford to shell out 30k every night.

Past chapter 9, you can return to sleep in this hotel by talking to Umbra.

From personal experience, I've run for 2 in-game days straight (gotta max out Survival!) and fought every dropship along the way, as well as captured an outpost. I didn't notice any penalties during these fights.

Comment: So if at 2 days 23 hours sleep I go to a diner and get some food it will expire an hour later? This sounds unlikely. It feels more likely that this is just related to the fact that food buffs are limited duration. Or are there other non-food buffs that you get that might require rest?

Comment: @Chris I found an explanation.

Comment: Excellent find with the status buffs. Do you know what kind of status buffs these refer to? For example, will Ignis's Enchant still work after staying awake for three days?

Comment: glad to see FF games are finally getting realistic.

Comment: @djechlin This is not remotely realistic.  After being sleep deprived for 3 days, you should risk decapitating yourself with melee weapons, not "no longer gets positive buffs".

Comment: @Nelson The sarcasm passed about a mile above your head...

Comment: @Chris It definitely doesn't apply to food buffs. I've run around for a week straight and still got food buffs fine.

Answer (score 11):

Apart from the occasional complaint of your crew there isn't really any penalty involved with being awake for several days.

Now this doesn't mean it's a good idea to stay awake forever since the only way to level up is sleeping.

After some time you will simply be too low of a level to fight certain enemies (especially enemies that can lock onto you with ranged attacks) and you might not be able to progress any further without the extra stats you'd get from leveling up.

Also If you decide to stay awake for longer during low levels there isn't really much to do during the nighttime apart from running away from high levelled monsters.

Sources: Haven't slept in 12 days.

Comment: "Sources: Haven't slept in 12 days." Are you referring to your FFXV party, or yourself? :)

Comment: Well, themselves obviously.