# Is there a downside to sleeping all the time?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

When you go to sleep anywhere you seem to get up at 6 in the morning. If you go to sleep at 5AM not much time passes but if you sleep later in the morning you'll be out for almost an entire day (seemingly, I've not done extensive experiments). Is this a problem?

Are there any mechanics in the game that are based on the amount of time that has passed?

For the purposes of this question I'm not counting things that require a certain time of day such as the hunts where your target only comes out at night. They require certain times of day but the amount of time passed isn't relevant.

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294243/is-there-a-downside-to-going-multiple-days-without-sleeping

Comment: @ZeroStack: Yup. That's the one that reminded me I wanted to ask this question (and indeed inspired the title). :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there are no penalties for sleeping more, aside from not being able to gain a massive amount of EXP all at once, as mentioned in my answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/294244/162442).

However, a potential benefit to sleeping excessively is that if you choose to camp outside, Ignis' dishes can give you various buffs for the following day, which can be greatly beneficial. (My favorite buffs are ones that put Prompto's HP on par with the rest of the party)

Comment: Cool. My thinking was about going to a motel for the XP bonus and then immediately heading to a campsite so Ignis can cook some tasty food. and we can all get nice buffs. Thanks for the confirmation. :)

Comment: Someone will correct me if I'm remembering wrong, but I want to say in the demo, there were no recipes that didn't use ingredients, so a downside could have been running out of everything to get buffs with.  This appears to have been changed, before release, though, so it's moot, at this point.

Comment: In the full game there are I believe two dishes that do not require any items to cook, toast, and rice balls I believe. @Khale_Kitha

Comment: @Ramirez Yeah, that was the change, I was referring to.  I want to say that  remember all of the recipes costing ingredients, in the demo.  (Causing me to frequently sleep without using any because I have a habit of NEVER using items, in RPGs.  Oops!)

Comment: Currently I have camped about three times (before I actually found the camper vans) and probably have ingredients for about 50 recipes at least so I'm not too worried about running out of ingredients but at the same time I am the same and tend to hoard things. The main reason I might not is because I want ignis's cooking skill to go up! :)

Comment: This is.mostly correct, but one small downside is that it'll run down your timer on a chocobo rental if you have one. They're dirt cheap so it's really minor, though.